# What is mean by fatal error in PHP?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function var_dumb()

[image]

What does this mean?

Comment: Please read document:http://www.careerride.com/PHP-types-errors.aspx

Comment: Did you search this function name its not `var_dumb` its `var_dump`, check this : https://eval.in/614206

Comment: it means PHP died.  And you killed it :(

Comment: Fatal errors:
These are critical errors - for example, instantiating an object of a non-existent class, or calling a non-existent function. These errors cause the immediate termination of the script, and PHP's default behavior is to display them to the user when they take place.

Comment: There could not have been a better error message than the one you were given. `Fatal`  can be seen in every English dictionary under the sun. Then it clearly mentions the function you called is undefined. What should we help you with on top of that?

Comment: var_dumb XD XD XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. `var_dumb` should be `var_dump`. Because PHP doesn't know a function by the name of `var_dumb`, it doesn't know what to do. A fatal exception is thrown, and execution of the script halts.

You can read more about PHP exceptions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Answer (score 6):

> What is mean by fatal error

It's an error that caused the script to abort and exit immediately. All statements after the fatal error are never executed.

```
<?php
echo 'line 1';
$a = new FakeClass(); // fatal error. Class doesn't exist so PHP aborts
echo 'line 2'; // <- never executed
```

Non-fatal errors don't abort the script

```
<?php
echo 'line 1';
$a = 7/0; // 'Non-fatal error: Division by zero'
echo 'line 2'; // <- executed and printed to the screen
```

In your case, since you used a function that PHP doesn't know `var_dumb()` a fatal error occurred.  The function you're looking for is `var_dump()`

I strongly recommend you use an editor that will alert you to errors as you code. It will safe you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

**PHP** doesn't have `var_dumb` method, correct method name is `var_dump`.

> **Fatal errors** are critical errors - for example, instantiating an
>   object of a non-existent class, or calling a non-existent function.
>   These errors cause the immediate termination of the script, and PHP's
>   default behavior is to display them to the user when they take place.

So in your case you're calling **non-existent function** and it throws fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

"Fatal Error", as it's name indicates, is Fatal : it stop the execution of the script / program.

There is a hack using output buffering that will let you log certain fatal errors, but there's no way to continue a script after a fatal error occurs - that's what makes it fatal!

If your script is timing out you can use [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/set%5Ftime%5Flimit) to give it more time to execute.

If you are using PHP to generate web pages and get a Fatal error related to [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) which, by defaults, equals 30 seconds, you are certainly doing something that really takes too mych time : users won't probably wait for so long to get the page.

Answer (score 0):

Fatal error is occurred due to the use of undefined function. When a function is called without providing its definition, the php compiler generates a fatal error.

```
<?php
function add($a, $b)
{
  $sum = $a + $b;
echo "sum is = " . $sum;
}
 $a = 2;
 $b = 4;
add($a, $b);
sub($a, $b);

?>
```

**Note:In this code sub function give us fatal error because it is called without defination.**