# Severity of exception codes

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, error-code

I am trying to sort out error and exception handlers. With a fatal error, I send myself a text message, and with other errors I get an email. (I added the arrays at the end in case they may be useful.)

For errors there is https://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php I but cannot find anything similar for exceptions.

I believe I can set my own exception values but are there agreed severity levels for general exceptions, `PDOExceptions` etc. The only place I find severity mentioned is in `ErrorException`. (I only use PDOExceptions at the moment but am trying to catch other "general" ones.)

Is a severity helper chart available somewhere? I freely admit I am struggling with exceptions.

PS I had a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorexception.getseverity.php but that looks like it is for errors being sent as exceptions. I am quite confused now.

---

Error code arrays in case they are useful.

```
$phpErrorCodes = array (
1   => "E_ERROR",
2   => "E_WARNING",
4   => "E_PARSE",
8   => "E_NOTICE",
16  => "E_CORE_ERROR",
32  => "E_CORE_WARNING",
64  => "E_COMPILE_ERROR",
128 => "E_COMPILE_WARNING",
256 => "E_USER_ERROR",
512 => "E_USER_WARNING",
1024 => "E_USER_NOTICE",
2048 => "E_STRICT  E_ALL",
4096 => "E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR",
8192 => "E_DEPRECATED",
16384=> "E_USER_DEPRECATED",
32767=> "E_ALL");

$phpErrorCodesFatal = array (
1   => "E_ERROR",
16  => "E_CORE_ERROR",
64  => "E_COMPILE_ERROR",
4096 => "E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR");

$phpErrorCodesFatalNumberOnly = array (
    1   ,
    16  ,
    64  ,
    4096);

//4096 recoverable but dangerous so treated as fatal
```

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Are there severity codes for exceptions.

Comment: No, exceptions don't have codes. They're organized in a class hierarchy.

Comment: Oh OK - so how do I know if they are important (Nothing was written to the database) vs fairly trivial (Your camel case word had to converted to all lower case) if such exist. For some reason I cannot get my head around exceptions at all. Errors seem straightforward.

Comment: Usually exceptions are all severe, as they'll halt the script if you don't catch them.

Comment: Unhandled exceptions would show up as PHP Warning. Other than that, there's no generally agreed-upon severity classification. Technically all exceptions ought to qualify actual errors. But they're widely just utilized for signaling and development-time notices (e.g. parameter type checks)

Comment: I have a PDOexception where I do a rollback if the database action does not complete properly and sends me a text (failing to write or read the DB is pretty drastic) but I really have no idea what I am doing other than that. I may possibly only need PDO exceptions now but moving forward 7 gets rid of errors for exceptions so I fear I will be screwed.

Comment: Mario I know that one but... don't really understand it. So if I don't do anything then exceptions turn to errors. How will this work in PHP 7. Forgive the incredibly dumb questions I am seriously floundering. (I was with errors too but then it all came much clearer).

Comment: If you really want to [catch PDO exceptions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#catch) you can, but generally you do not need to catch errors/exceptions. Design your code in such a way that errors are only thrown in exceptional situations.

Comment: "Design your code in such a way that errors are only thrown in exceptional situations" ROFLMHO. I wish! My code is horrible. Fortunately it will never get out into the real world. And I mean REALLY horrible. But yep I 100% agree with you if you know what you are doing. This is sort of a hobby project. So, as a rule of thumb I should treat exceptions as fatal errors?

Answer (score 3):

## Exceptions

Let me try to clarify some misconceptions here.

> Are there severity codes for exceptions?

No. All exceptions are severe.
An exception will stop the execution of your script. They are used to prevent the execution of the code which follows if the preceding code could not be executed.

> How do I know if they are important?

All exceptions are important. When an exception is triggered it tells you as a developer that something unexpected has happened in the code. The code which you have written simply did not anticipate this happening and to prevent undefined behaviour it should stop processing immediately.

> Unhandled exceptions would show up as PHP Warning. - [mario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905814/severity-of-exception-codes/59444551#comment100356691_56905814)

That is not true. Any unhandled exception will be converted to [PHP Fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38670763/1839439). If your application doesn't know how to handle an exceptional situation then PHP must immediately stop! It is not a warning you can ignore or silence; it's a fatal error.

> As a rule of thumb I should treat exceptions as fatal errors?

Not necessarily. In rare cases a developer might expect a particular piece of code to throw an exception, which is possible to recover from or work around. The code logic anticipates something going wrong and has a way around the problem. If the exception is caught and handled this will not result in a fatal error.

The difference between an exception and a fatal error is that you can catch and recover from an exception, but not from a fatal error.

> So if I don't do anything then exceptions turn to errors.

If you have not caught the exception and you do not have your own error handled implemented then PHP will default to the built-in error handler. The logic is that it will stop the script and throw an error with the exception as a message. This error will then, based on your configuration settings, either be logged on the server or displayed to the user.

## Errors

PHP has a bad history. One of the problems with early PHP versions was that it was very lenient when it comes to badly written code. It would either try to guess what the correct action should be or merely warn the user about some serious problem. The outcome of this was that a lot of developers learned to simply ignore the warnings, notices and sometimes even errors.

With PHP 7 few things have changed.

PHP 7 changes how most errors are reported by PHP. Instead of reporting errors through the traditional error reporting mechanism used by PHP 5, most errors are now reported by throwing [Error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) exceptions. An error is still not an exception, but it behaves like one. You can catch the error and if you don't you will still see *"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: ..."*.

Modern PHP functionalities will now use exceptions. This means that userland code should also try to follow the same approach. Throw an exception when your code should stop the execution (don't use `die/exit` for this) and only catch them when when you know how to recover.

With future PHP releases the notices and warnings might be changed to Error exceptions. Don't ignore them now. Treat all of them as severe problems in your code and fix them now.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, the general advice with exceptions is that you should catch them all - in that sense, all unhandled exceptions are severe.

However, you could still classify exceptions in your system in the way that you want. Let's say that at the top level of your app you have a call that enters the main app:

```
try
{
    $this->mainApp();
}
catch (SeriousRuntimeException $e)
{
    $this->handleSeriousError($e);
}
catch (TrivialRuntimeException $e)
{
    $this->handleTrivialError($e);
}
```

Then in your code you can throw a `SeriousRuntimeException` or a `TrivialRuntimeException` as you see fit. In some cases you will have external exceptions to deal with, and you will need to convert them like so:

```
try
{
    $this->databaseOperation();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    // Copy the exception properties that are important to you.
    // Throw the appropriate severity based on what handler you
    // want to run.
    throw new SeriousRuntimeException($e->getMessage());
}
```

In this example I assume that both exception types are fatal, but they are handled differently. It is conceivable that you could have an exception type that is so trivial that the app keeps running (e.g. in a listener loop - it logs the fault and then carries on).